# Running netlogo with 64 bit Java from a batch file

Tags: netlogo

To overcome memory constraints I'm trying to run Netlogo with a 64 bit version of JRE.  I have tried using the example at http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/We-found-a-solution-for-Out-of-Memory-Errors-td5005459.html.  As recommended I have created a desktop based batch file with the following code included:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\java" -Xmx10g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetLogo 5.1.0\NetLogo.jar"
```

I have updated my file path to the those used by my system, but when I load Netlogo the extension directory is not found.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java" -Xmx2g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\NetLogo 5.1.0\NetLogo.jar"
```

Can someone please let me know how I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What directory are you running that command from? For NetLogo to find extensions, sample models, etc., the current working directory at startup time must be the NetLogo directory. So your script should `chdir` there first.